# Hi I don't know why im not able to change the "add to cart" button to "out of stock" when I place the "disabled" in the iteriration is not working

Tags: button

Hi I don't know why im not able to change the "add to cart" button to "out of stock"  when I place the "disabled"  in the iteriration is not working

```js
export default function Product(props) {
      const { product } = props;
    
      const { state, dispatch: ctxDispatch } = useContext(Store);
      const {
        cart: { cartItems },
      } = state;
    
      const addToCartHandler = async (item) => {
        const existItem = cartItems.find((x) => x._id === product._id);
        const quantity = existItem ? existItem.quantity + 1 : 1;
        const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${item._id}`);
        if (data.countInStock < quantity) {
          window.alert("Sorry. Product is out of stock");
          return;
        }
        ctxDispatch({`enter code here`
          type: "CART_ADD_ITEM",
          payload: { ...item, quantity },
        });
      };
      return (
        <Card>
          <Link to={`/product/${product.slug}`}>
            <img src={product.image} className="card-img-top" alt={product.name} />
          </Link>
          <Card.Body>
            <Link to={`/product/${product.slug}`}>
              <Card.Title>{product.name}</Card.Title>
            </Link>
            <Rating rating={product.rating} numReviews={product.numReviews} />
            <Card.Text>${product.price}</Card.Text>
            {product.countInStock === 0 ? (
              <Button variant="light" disabled>
                Out of stock
              </Button>
            ) : (
              <Button onClick={() => addToCartHandler(product)}>Add to cart</Button>
            )}
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

lets see that in the data i.e data.js did you have mentioned   countInStock: 0, or not mostly i think ,you have may give countInStock: '' , ----  so change countInStock: '' ,  To  countInStock: 0, in data.js

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).